# Java Representation of C Enum

Tags: java, c, enums

I am porting to Java a bytecode compiler written in C.  In the C implementation, the set of operations is represented in an enum:

```
typedef enum {
  SOME_OP,
  ANOTHER_OP,
  //Etc.
} Operations;
```

Operations are then mixed with numeric arguments in an array defined as:

```
uint8_t* opsAndArgs;
```

For example, opsAndArgs might hold:

```
{SOME_OP, 42, ANOTHER_OP, 99, 03, DIFFERENT_OP, RANDOM_OP, 14, etc.}
```

Finally, a function in the C program iterates through opsAndArgs and switches on operators, consuming arguments as appropriate:

```
int i = 0;

while (i < opsAndArgs.length) {
  switch (opsAndArgs[i] {
    case SOME_OP:
      handleSomeOp(opsAndArgs[i+1]);
      i = i + 2; break;
    case ANOTHER_OP:
      handleAnotherOp(opsAndArgs[i+1], opsAndArgs[i+2]);
      i = i + 3; break;
    case DIFFERENT_OP:
      handleDifferentOp();
      i = i + 1; break;
    Etc.
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can do the same thing in Java?  I.e., create an Enum that I can mix into an array with numeric values, and still have the ability to switch on Enum-defined operators while treating the remaining values as arguments?

It seems like the original program is taking advantage of some feature of C enums such that they are mix-able with uint8_t values.

Comment: In C an `enum` is essentially a set of named integer constant(s). So you could use integer constants in Java to get the same effect (and very similar code). Or you could create an `enum` that can be converted to and from integers

Comment: you can use a hashtable to map the string of the opcode to the integer value of it, this has the benefit of being able to make a similar hashtable to reverse the opcode back into the string representation. eg `HashMap<String, Integer> opsAndArgs= new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{ put("SOME_OP", 0); put("ANOTHER_OP", 1); put("DIFFERENT_OP", 2); put("RANDOM_OP", 3);}};`. Then you can `opsAndArgs["RANDOM_OP"]` to get your value back. Alternatively you can hardcode the each constant similar to `final static int RANDOM_OP = 3;` in the class you are using them, or another Operations class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike in C, an enum in Java is an object. That means that the only way to mix the them with numbers is with a `List<Object>` or `Object[]`.

Every enum does have an `ordinal()` value that is an int. These are not compile-time constants though, so you can't use them in switch statements*.

I think that you have some options:

1. Go for the `List<Object>` / `Object[]` solution. If you only perform switching on the operations, you can do this with a combination of `instanceof` and `switch`

```
if (opsAndArgs[i] instanceof Operation operation) { // **
    switch (operation) {
        case SOME_OP: ...
    }
}
```

2. Forget the enum and go for a constants class:

```
final class Operation {
    public static final int SOME_OP = 1;
    // etc

    private Operation() {}
}
```

3. Define int constants for each enum constant. Each enum constant must return one of these, and you'll need to have a lookup (static method) on the enum class to find the enum constant based on the int constant. Don't trust on `ordinal()` as constants because if you change the order of enum constants the ordinal values change as well.

I think the main question you have to ask yourself is: do you *need* an enum? Or is the constants class good enough? Because that's definitely the easier of the solutions.

* Yet? I'm not fully up-to-speed with the latest changes to switch pattern matching...

** That's syntax finalized in Java 16. In older versions, use `opsAndArgs[i] instanceof Operation` in combination with a new variable inside the if: `Operation operation = (Operation) opsAndArgs[i];`

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view:

- Keep the structure of the C byte code interpreter, else life gets too complicated!
- `opsAndArgs` has to be a byte array. We are talking about Java byte code here. Some values have to be interpreted as bytes, some as shorts, ... and the program counter needs to advance in byte-sized steps.
- Use `static final byte` for opcodes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working solution in Java. Obviously, there are some things that were unclear (for example, I don't know what your `handleXXXXOp` methods do), so liberties were taken. Otherwise, this works just fine in Java 17.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class SOQ_20220605_2
{

   private sealed interface Value
   {
   
      public static List<Value> asList(Object... uncheckedValues)
      {
      
         Objects.requireNonNull(uncheckedValues);
         
         final List<Value> values = new ArrayList<>();
         
         for (var each : uncheckedValues)
         {
         
            values.add(
               switch(each)
               {
               
                  case null         -> throw new NullPointerException("No nulls allowed");
                  case Integer i    -> new Argument(i);
                  case String s     -> Operation.valueOf(s.toUpperCase());
                  case Argument a   -> a;
                  case Operation o  -> o;
                  default           -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected type! each = " + each);
               
               }
            );
         
         }
         
         return values;
      
      }
   
   }
   
   private enum Operation implements Value
   {
      
      SOME_OP,
      ANOTHER_OP,
      DIFFERENT_OP,
      RANDOM_OP,
      ;
      
   }
   
   private record Argument(int num) implements Value {}

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   
      final List<Value> opsAndArgs =
         Value.asList
         (
            "SOME_OP",
            42,
            "ANOTHER_OP",
            99,
            3,
            "DIFFERENT_OP",
            "RANDOM_OP",
            14
         );

         final int result = calculateResult(opsAndArgs);
         
         System.out.println(result);

   }
   
   private static int calculateResult(List<Value> opsAndArgs)
   {
   
         int i = 0;

         while (i < opsAndArgs.size())
         {
         
            if (opsAndArgs.get(i) instanceof Operation operation)
            {
            
               i = 
                  switch (operation)
                  {
               
                     case SOME_OP -> 
                     {
                     
                        handleSomeOp(
                              opsAndArgs.get(i + 1)
                           );
      
                        yield i + 2;
                     
                     }
                     
                     case ANOTHER_OP ->
                     {
                     
                        handleAnotherOp(
                              opsAndArgs.get(i + 1),
                              opsAndArgs.get(i + 2)
                           );
      
                        yield i + 3;
                     
                     }
                  
                     case DIFFERENT_OP ->
                     {
                     
                        handleDifferentOp();
      
                        yield i + 1;
                     
                     }
                     
                     case RANDOM_OP ->
                     {
                        
                        yield i + 4;
                        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This has not been implemented yet.");
                     
                     }
                  
                  };
               
            }
         
         }
         
         return i;
   
   }
   
   private static void handleSomeOp(Value value)
   {
   
      //do something
   
   }

   private static void handleAnotherOp(Value value1, Value value2)
   {
   
      //do something
   
   }

   private static void handleDifferentOp()
   {
   
      //do something
   
   }

}
```

We create a common interface called `Value`, so that we can have a domain of acceptable values for our `List<Value>`. Then, we make it sealed, so that only the types we allow can be considered a `Value`. Those 2 types are `Argument` and `Operation`. We also have a method `asList` that handles taking in the array that you described in your question. Now, you can pass in your operations and arguments as parameters. If you wanted to pass in `SOME_OP`, you can either pass it in as `Operation.SOME_OP` or as a `String` via `"SOME_OP"`. The method can handle both ways currently, but I am choosing to pass in each operation as a `String`. Same for the arguments. If you wanted to pass in `42`, you could either pass it in as `new Argument(42)`, or you could pass it in naked as an `int` via `42`. The method can handle both ways currently, but I am choosing to pass in each argument as an `int`.

`Operation` is an `enum` that holds all of the operations you defined. If you want to add more operations, simply add them to this enum, compile, then update any of the switch statements that now fail compilation.

`Argument` is a `record` that holds arguments. Having it be an explicit type helps us separate the arguments from the operations when they are together.

The main method gathers up the values in basically the same way you did, then calls the method `calculateResult`, with our `List<Value> values` as the parameter.

`calculateResult` is basically the switch statement and while loop that you had in your original question. This is where most of the liberties were taken. And your switch case didn't specify what happens when it comes across an argument, so I built my solution to silently ignore arguments in the `switch` statement.